# Proving the continuity of a logarithmic function in a metric space

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, metric-spaces

Let $(X, d)$ be a metric space, $a \in X$, and consider the function $f: X \setminus \{a\} \to \mathbb{R}$ given by
$f(x)=log⁡(d(x,a)).$
Then $f$ is continuous. Prove or disprove it.

My idea:

Let $(X, d)$ be a metric space, $a \in X$, and consider the function $f: X \setminus \{a\} \to \mathbb{R}$ given by $f(x) = \log(d(x,a))$. We want to prove that $f$ is continuous.

Let $(x_n)$ be a sequence in $X \setminus \{a\}$ converging to some point $x \in X \setminus \{a\}$. We need to show that $(f(x_n))$ converges to $f(x)$.

Since $(x_n)$ converges to $x$, for any $\epsilon > 0$, there exists a positive integer $N$ such that for all $n \geq N$, $d(x_n, x) < \epsilon$.

Now, consider the sequence $(f(x_n)) = (\log(d(x_n, a)))$. We want to show that this sequence converges to $f(x) = \log(d(x, a))$.

Let's analyze the difference $|f(x_n) - f(x)| = |\log(d(x_n, a)) - \log(d(x, a))|$. We can rewrite this expression as $|\log\left(\frac{d(x_n, a)}{d(x, a)}\right)|$.

Since the logarithm function is continuous, we can apply the continuity of logarithm to the expression inside the absolute value. Since $x_n$ converges to $x$, we have $d(x_n, a) \to d(x, a)$ as $n \to \infty$. Therefore, we can conclude that $\lim_{n \to \infty} |f(x_n) - f(x)| = \lim_{n \to \infty} |\log\left(\frac{d(x_n, a)}{d(x, a)}\right)| = |\log(1)| = 0$.

This shows that $(f(x_n))$ converges to $f(x)$ as $n \to \infty$. Hence, the function $f: X \setminus \{a\} \to \mathbb{R}$ given by $f(x) = \log(d(x, a))$ is continuous.

Is my proof correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easy observation,

define,
$g:X\setminus\{a\} \to \mathbb{R}$
$f(x)=d(x,a)$
This is a continuous function
(proof is easy)

define

$h:(0,\infty) \to \mathbb{R}$

$h(x)=\log(x)$
is also continuous function

Now, $f=h\circ g$ is also continuous

What you have done, It is right but after using sequential criteria again you use continuity in last .Rather than this ,you can use basic continuity of composition of functions.

Comment: and how can I easily show that $f(x)=d(x,a)$ ist a continuous function? right now, I can't see an easy way to prove it

Comment: $|f(x)-f(y)|=|d(x,a)-d(y,a)|≤d(x,y)$